# How to count the most common value in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysql-num-rows

At the moment I've got the following code:

```
$forummost = mysql_query("

 SELECT door, 
 COUNT(door) AS doorCount 
 FROM forum_posts 
 GROUP BY door 
 ORDER BY COUNT(door) 
 DESC

");
$forummostc = mysql_num_rows($forummost);
$forummostf = mysql_fetch_assoc($forummost);
```

Can somebody explain me why **mysql_num_rows($forummost)** doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting or output?

Comment: I get "227" but when I SELECT the same user in PHPMyAdmin SQL, I get: "1158"

Comment: The number of rows in your return array is the number of distinct doors.

Comment: @Mossawi: can you edit your question and post expected and actual output there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) selects only the different values of that column in mysql. In your case, as pointed out, it selects as many rows as different `door` values are there.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_rows` counts the number of rows returned by the query. Your query is `what is the count for each door` so only one row for each door is returned.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I tested, it works..

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
if (!$link) 
{ 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'."</br>"; 


$forummost = mysql_query("
    SELECT door, 
COUNT(door) AS doorCount 
FROM forum_posts 
GROUP BY door 
ORDER BY COUNT(door) 
DESC
");


$forummostc = mysql_num_rows($forummost);

if ($forummostc == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($forummost)) {
    echo $row["door"];
    echo $row["doorCount"];

}

mysql_free_result($forummost);

mysql_close($link); 

?>
```